# Multidimensional Arrays Multiplication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I have the following three arrays in Matlab:

A size: 2xMxN

B size: MxN

C size: 2xN

Is there any way to remove the following loop to speed things up?

```
D = zeros(2,N);
for i=1:N
    D(:,i) = A(:,:,i) * ( B(:,i) - A(:,:,i)' * C(:,i) );
end
```

Thanks

Comment: [This thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/111447) is what you're looking for. Though it seems the answer is, there is no faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do without the `for` loop, but whether this leads to a speed-up depends on the values of `M` and `N`.

Your idea of a generalized matrix multiplication is interesting, but it is not exactly to the point here, because through the repeated use of the index `i` you effectively take a generalized diagonal of a generalized product, which means that most of the multiplication results are not needed.

The trick to implement the computation without a loop is to a) match matrix dimensions through `reshape`, b) obtain the matrix product through `bsxfun(@times, …)` and `sum`, and c) get rid of the resulting singleton dimensions through `reshape`:

```
par = B - reshape(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(C, 2, 1, N)), 1), M, N);
D = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(par, 1, M, N)), 2), 2, N);
```

`par` is the value of the inner expression in parentheses, `D` the final result.

As said, the timing depends on the exact values. For `M = 100` and `N = 1000000` I find a speed-up by about a factor of two, for `M = 10000` and `N = 10000` the loop-less implementation is actually a bit slower.

Comment: Unfortunately for the combinations of N and M in my application the loop-less implementation is slower, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the following

D=tprod(A,[1 -3 2],B-tprod(A,[-3 1 2],C,[-3 2]),[-3 2]);

cuts the time taken. I did a few tests and found the time was cut in about half.

tprod is available at
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16275

tprod requires that A, B and C are full (not sparse).